# What is the best word describing the nature of expiring in a short amount of time, connoting "losing public attention"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective that describes the nature of expiring, connoting a sense of losing public attention, in a very short amount of time? For example,

> In a fast-paced era, news articles are ____.
>
> During the 1990s, compared with traditional technologies, computer  technologies are ___; for example, a new generation of CPU technologies usually comes out every one to two years.

(I thought about "perishable," but it does not seem connoting "losing public attention.")

Comment: @choster Thanks I updated the examples.

Comment: What is the best word describing *rapidly falling out of fashion*? That's nine less words then your title; good luck getting down to just one. *fleeting, short-lived*, and *ephemeral* don't connote "losing public attention". *evanescent* connotes both but colloquially has only one meaning: a band's name.

Comment: Doesn't fit your examples and not a single word, so this is a comment only; the term 'shelf life' could be used... 'computer technologies have short shelf life...

Comment: The second example has a confusing temporal location; initially I'd have assumed from "during the 1990s" the sentence is giving a historical account, which is in conflict with "are"/"comes" (implying the sentence is describing the present day)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I like the word [**fleeting**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fleeting) for this:

> : passing swiftly : TRANSITORY
>   // … the often *fleeting* nature of fame and fortune …
>   — Tom Sinclair

So:

> In a fast-paced era, news articles are *fleeting*.

Of course, the referenced *transitory* would also work, depending on the style of speech to be conveyed.

Answer (score 32):

I know there's an accepted answer, but another word that comes to mind (a synonym of fleeting) is [ephemeral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ephemeral).

> lasting a very short time
> // ephemeral pleasures

Comment: This is the best fit for the sample sentence provided.

Answer (score 23):

One could use [short-lived](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short-lived).

> not living or lasting long

Answer (score 8):

I think a better word for this would be *evanescent*:

> **evanescent** *adj*
>   1. vanishing; fading away; fleeting.
>   2. tending to become imperceptible; scarcely perceptible.
>   <sub>[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/evanescent)</sub>

Right on both counts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96831/discussion-on-answer-by-robusto-what-is-the-best-word-describing-the-nature-of-e).

Answer (score 3):

It's a phrase rather than a word, so aplogies on that but you could describe it as a "flash in the pan"
Def: something that happened only once or for a short time and was not repeated:

Comment: This was exactly what I thought of at first. It means lasting a short time, but is also widely associated with popular opinion. While not a single word, it better captures the loss of public attention than the accepted answer. This answer could be improved by adding a link and a sample sentence.

Comment: Similar phrase would be something along the lines of "[his/her/its] 15 minutes are almost over."

Comment: I was thinking "flash in the pan" when I first read the question. The only potential argument against is that it's *too* specific with the "not repeated" part of the definition; since the OP didn't specify that the success couldn't happen again, it may not fit. That's incredibly nitpicky though and I agree that it's a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add one more option, I like **waning**

> **wane** *verb* (used without object), waned, wan·ing
>   1. to decrease in strength, intensity, etc.:
>   "Her enthusiasm for the cause is waning"
>   2. to decline in power, importance, prosperity, etc.:
>   "Colonialism began to wane after World War II"
>   3. to draw to a close; approach an end:
>   "Summer is waning."

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wane)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [Disposable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disposable):

> *Adjective*
>   designed for or capable of being thrown away after being used or used up:
>   disposable plastic spoons; a disposable cigarette lighter.

As, in my opinion, that captures the idea best. When everything becomes disposable – news, information, items, culture – they also become worthless.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of [faddish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faddish)

> fad *noun*
>   : a practice or interest followed for a time with exaggerated zeal : CRAZE

Of course that also denotes a quick *entrance* to the limelight, which may not be what you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

I would also use the word "**[Obsolescent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obsolescent)**". So,

In a fast-paced era, news articles are *obsolescent*.

***From Wikitionary:***

> Adjective
>   **Obsolescent** (comparative more obsolescent, superlative most
>   obsolescent) 
>   1.In the process of becoming obsolete, but not obsolete yet.

***From Wikipedia:***

> **Obsolescence** (noun) is the state of being which occurs when an object,
>   service, or practice is no longer wanted even though it may still be
>   in good working order. ... Typically, obsolescence is preceded by a
>   gradual decline in popularity.

Answer (score 0):

Answers have not all been related to computer technology, so I add "a one-day wonder".

The Collins Dictionary has [this](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-one-day-wonder)

> **a one-day wonder**
>   or a nine-day wonder
>
> something or someone that is interesting, exciting, or successful for only a very short time, and does not have any lasting value

It certainly does describe *some* technology though I would not like to name one.

Answer (score 0):

**Transient** could work here, particularly for the computer example as it occurs more often in computing nomenclature and is keyword in the Java programming language, used to indicate that an item data is short-lived and not intended to be saved to a long term storage medium through a process known as serialization.

For a multi-word answer (and I do think the "in the public mind" aspect of this question generally tends towards multi-words) I quite like **here today, gone tomorrow**