# A word like ethereal that also means quickly vanishing

Tags: word-choice

This is a question for English wordsmiths. Is there a word that "feels" like the word "ethereal" that means something ethereal that quickly disappears.  Or is "ethereal" the correct word choice for this? Ethereal was the first word that popped into my head for this.

From the various definitions that I've looked at for ethereal, it says delicate, beautiful, heavenly, etc. but not necessarily quickly vanishing, except for the secondary definitions related to ether that suggests it evaporates. I'm just wondering if there is a better word than this.

I'm using the term "ethereal skill" to describe a certain type of pilot skill (instrument flying) that requires tremendous practice to achieve proficiency, and once proficiency is achieved it is a beautiful thing, but if you don't practice it regularly, that skill vanishes after a few weeks.

USAGE:
Instrument proficiency is an ethereal skill that once obtained must be maintained through constant and regular practice.

Comment: I feel like [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505776/what-is-the-best-word-describing-the-nature-of-expiring-in-a-short-amount-of-tim](the linked question) is not a duplicate. That question is asking about things that become irrelevant or unfashionable quickly; this one is asking about things that become unusable or cease to exist quickly. Good answers to the one are not necessarily good answers to the other.

Comment: Though I'm glad Robusto has added an (ultimate) close-vote, mine was for lack of research; looking up synonyms for 'ethereal' quickly provides the answers below.

Comment: @TannerSwett: The top answers here are also there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth not true, I did more than a quick search, and these were the synonyms that I found "bodiless, formless, immaterial, incorporeal, insubstantial, nonmaterial, nonphysical, spiritual, unbodied, unsubstantial". Notice the lack of "ephemeral." Also, my original question states that I searched various definitions, and even listed some of them. I didn't list the synonyms that I found because they were all irrelevant as you can see from my list. I have no problem with your close-vote, but your reason for the vote makes me think you only read the title and not the text. :)

Comment: Lack of research _shown_  (and correctly attributed and linked). (Check at the Help Center). // [Thesaurus.net](https://www.thesaurus.net/ethereal) gives vanishing, evanescen(ce); evanescent leads to ephemeral, fleeting, transient ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, fair enough, I concede research was shown, but not attributed and linked.

Comment: Provided sensible research is done, shown, linked and attributed, it can be negative. This prevents contributors all futilely checking the same sources, and perhaps one or two will think of a tangential way of finding a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You are probably looking for the word *ephemeral*.

> [ephemeral](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ephemeral): Lasting for a very short time.

Comment: This should be a comment. And why am I the first to close-vote?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: If I had posted it as a comment, somebody would have said "this should be posted as an answer."

Comment: So now you can convert it to a community Wiki to show that you value site integrity above inappropriate upvoting.

Answer (score 29):

***evanescent*** is a good match - definitions focus on loss and vaporous qualities. It seems to be applied most often to the loss of things with positive connotation.

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evanescent) defines it with : "tending to vanish like vapor",

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/evanescent) with "lasting for only a short time, then disappearing quickly and being forgotten"

[Century Dictionary Online](http://www.global-language.com/CENTURY/) has a number of useful definitions and quotes. I like "Vanishing or apt to vanish or be dissipated, like vapor; passing away; fleeting: as, the pleasures and joys of life are *evanescent*.

Also from Century, this quote: "He [Wordsworth] seems to have caught and fixed forever in immutable grace the most evanescent and intangible of our intuitions, the very ripple-marks on the remotest shores of being." - Lowell, Among my Books

Comment: Chris, excellent answer, and welcome!  The definition is spot on. :)

Answer (score 8):

> I think, at least in the context of the digital industry and knowledge economy, we can broadly define three types of skills – Enduring, Tansient [sic] and Transferable.
>
> **Transient skills** are those that change often and need regularly updating. Things like specific software packages, programming languages, tools, technologies, techniques and latest best practice.
>
> – *What Do We Mean By ‘Skills’ Anyway?* [hirschworks.com](https://www.hirschworks.com/what-do-we-mean-by-skills-anyway/)

If it's not like riding a bike, then it's a *transient* skill.

> ***transient***, adjective. 1a : passing especially quickly into and out of existence
>
> Synonyms: transient, transitory, ephemeral, momentary, fugitive, fleeting, evanescent
>
> – [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transient)

Skills that are 'use it or lose it' are *fleeting*.

> **fleeting**, adjective. passing swiftly : transitory
>
> – [Merriam-Webster](http://Merriam-Webster)

"Instrument proficiency is a [*transient/fleeting*] skill that once obtained must... [obviously be practiced (because you used either of those words)]."

Comment: The skills mentioned by the article you quoted are not transient because they are easily forgotten, but because they quickly become obsolete. As far as I could find, this usage is consistent, for example here: https://books.google.lu/books?id=2hFVavVJxZ8C&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%22transient+skills%22&source=bl&ots=sQGHiMMKXl&sig=ACfU3U2WTyDd4SxCduU-WOs0eoAJeTW2ng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjo77fnvL_nAhVUQkEAHYPfBZQQ6AEwCHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22transient%20skills%22&f=false

Comment: To continue with your metaphor, transient skills are not like riding a bicycle, but like riding a penny-farthing ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest **perishable**. It's usually used for food, of course, but I think it sounds fine as a metaphor.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/perishable) defines it as

> 1. (especially of food) likely to decay or go bad quickly.
>
> *‘the storage of perishable foods’*
>   *‘caviar is extremely perishable’*

You could write, *Instrument flying is a **perishable** skill. If you don't use it for a few weeks, it rots.*

Answer (score 1):

@Mazura's answer of ***transient*** is excellent and even "the recognized word," if the skill is lost because of *rapid change in the exterior world.* Another way to describe a rapidly changing world where you have to keep practicing your skill to stay relevant would be to call the situation an ***arms race*** or even a [***Red Queen's race***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Queen%27s_race).

But in your case of instrument flying, presumably the skill is lost because it *fades from the brain* after a few weeks, not because instrument panels and weather conditions change their fundamentals every few weeks.

Less mystical, but you could also just say that the skill **expires** — that it is ***expiring***. Or ***decaying***.

---

Your word ***ethereal*** is actually quite apt IMVHO, because there's at least some minor tradition in fantasy RPGs of using the word *ethereal* to refer to magical weapons that are powerful but time-limited.

- In *Diablo 2*: ["So an Ethereal weapon will potentially have the biggest damage of any weapon in the game, but it wouldn't last long."](https://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Ethereal)
- In *Hexx: Heresy of the Wizard*: ["Ethblade: Creates a weapon in a free hand. Allows double attacks..."](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/hexx/blob/master/hexx-manual.pdf) (but the ethereal weapons disappear after a certain amount of time or number of hits, I forget which)

However, plenty of games use the name *ethereal weapon* for weapons that have some powerful effect but do not have the tradeoff of "expiring," more like a traditional holy weapon.

- D&D 5th Edition has non-fragile [*ethereal weapons*](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Ethereal_Weapon_(5e_Equipment)) (their version of Hexx's *ethblade* spell is called [***spiritual weapon***](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spiritual%20Weapon#content) instead).
- *DotA 2* has non-fragile *ethereal weapons* as far as I can tell.
- *Nioh* has some kind of [*Ethereal* modifier](https://nioh.fandom.com/wiki/Grace_Bonuses) that does not connote fragility as far as I can tell.

So I'm fairly sure that most people wouldn't agree with my opinion that *ethereal* is an apt word to connote time-limited power. :)